# Reactjs cannot load images from json

Tags: reactjs, json

Apparently importing image url from json file doesn't work and gives such an output. But if i import them this way : {require("hardcoded url")} they work but if i use variables like in the image below the image doesn't load up or like : {require(project.image)} then the whole page goes to the background color.

react code:
[image]
json file:
[image]

OUTPUT:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add `require()` to all image keys in your JSON file.

example  :

**change** :   `"image": "images/personalewebsite.png",`
**to** : `"image": "require('images/personalewebsite.png')"`

this is a demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-edison-jeqvus)

Comment: thank you so much!!!  i also figured out the same solution later that night